# Extending existing singleton

Tags: javascript, jquery

I like the idea of using Singleton mentioned here http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/javascript-design-patterns-pt1-singleton-composite-facade.html:

```
    var Namespace = {
    Util: {
        util_method1: function() {…},
        util_method2: function() {…}
    },
    Ajax: {
        ajax_method: function() {…}
    },
    some_method: function() {…}
};
```

Let's say I have to add some methods and new namespace too (Namespace.Util2) later, how can I add methods without modifying the above code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is simply:

```
Namespace.Util.newUtilMethod = function () { };
```

To add a new namespace,

```
Namespace.Util2 = { /* definitions */ };
```

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace.util.newFunc = function () { };
```

or, if you're using jquery and want to add a bunch at once:

```
var newStuff = {
    newThing1: function () {...},
    newThing2: function () {...},
    newThing3: function () {...}
};

$.extend(namespace.util, newStuff);
```